# How to index List into elasticsearch via NEST c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I need to put a lot of entries from `List<Person>` into elasticsearch via NEST library. 
I can put one by one using loop and code below:

```
var person = new Person
{
    Id = "1",
    Firstname = "Martijn",
    Lastname = "Laarman"
};

var index = client.Index(person);
```

But seems like it works really slow. Is there any way for doing that more quickly via NEST?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the `BulkDescriptor` object.

Then you can do something as follow:

```
private readonly ElasticClient _client; //needs to be initialized in your code
public void Index(IEnumerable<Person> documents)
    {
        var bulkIndexer = new BulkDescriptor();

        foreach (var document in documents)
        {
            bulkIndexer.Index<Person>(i => i
                .Document(document)
                .Id(document.SearchDocumentId)
                .Index(_indexName));
        }

        _client.Bulk(bulkIndexer);
    }
```

The function `Index`, takes an IEnumerable of your type. So when you loop through your items to index, instead of adding each object to the index individually, use this function to pass the collection to, and it will bulk index the objects for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works faster that in the loop more than 100 times. In the loop I spent  more that hour for input 144k entities. By using bulk input I've spent 81 second.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)